# Book where the storyteller is a dog

Tags: story-identification, books, animals

The dog's owner is an alchemist. The dog talks to other animals, like the cat of a witch or the rat of a vampire, and reports about the ongoing battle to open the gates of hell, which can only be done every 666 years.

Answer (score 19):

This is [*A Night in the Lonesome October*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1464) by Roger Zelazny.

The dog, Snuff, belongs to Jack the Ripper (who is a good guy, or Closer, in the story), the cat is named Greymalk and belongs to a friendly antagonist named Jill, who is an Opener.  The Openers want to open a gateway to some outer dimension to allow the eldritch horrors there into the world.  (For various reasons.)

Jill is a witch and has a cat, but The Count's animal companion is a bat named Needle.  The rat (Bubo) "belongs" to The Good Doctor, except we find out at the end that The Good Doctor isn't actually a Player, and Bubo is just amusing himself and trying to fit in (as a talking animal).

Quoting from the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Night_in_the_Lonesome_October):

> The story reveals that once every few decades when the moon is full on the night of Halloween, the fabric of reality thins and doors may be opened between this world and the realm of the Great Old Ones. When these conditions are right, men and women with occult knowledge may gather at a specific ritual site to hold the doors closed, or to help fling them open. Should the Closers win, then the world will remain as it is until the next turning, but should the Openers succeed, then the Great Old Ones will come to Earth, to remake the world in their own image, enslaving or slaughtering the human race in the process. The Openers have never yet won. These meetings are often referred to as "The Game" or "The Great Game" by the participants, who try to keep the goings-on secret from the mundane population.
>
> The various "Players" during the Game depicted in the book are archetypal characters from Victorian Era gothic fiction – Jack the Ripper (only ever referred to as "Jack"), Dracula ("The Count"), Victor Frankenstein ("The Good Doctor"), and the Wolf Man (known as "Larry Talbot", the film character's name) all make appearances. In addition, there is a Witch ("Crazy Jill"), a Clergyman (Vicar Roberts), a Druid ("Owen"), a "Mad Monk" ("Rastov" – apparently modeled after Rasputin), and grave robbers or Hermetic occultists ("Morris and McCab" – based either on real-life grave robbers Burke and Hare[3] or a reference to a real hermetic of the time, MacGregor Mathers).

Comment: I was so certain I was an Opener when I read this as a young twentysomething.